# nodejs: Error: EADDRNOTAVAIL, Cannot assign requested address

Tags: javascript, sockets, node.js

I have the following node.js server running on 172.16.1.218:

```
var net=require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
        socket.write("Echo server\r\n");
        socket.pipe(socket);
});
server.listen(6001, "172.16.1.218");
```

I can telnet into it and it echos as expected.

I have the following node.js server running on 172.16.1.224:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

  // Every time someone connects, tell them hello and then close the connection.
  socket.addListener("connect", function () {
    sys.puts("Connection from " + socket.remoteAddress);
    socket.end("Hello World\n");
  });

});

// Fire up the server bound to port 7000 on localhost
server.listen(6001,"172.16.1.218");
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: EADDRNOTAVAIL, Cannot assign requested address
    at Server._doListen (net.js:1100:5)
    at net.js:1071:14
    at Object.lookup (dns.js:159:5)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1065:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hynese/Desktop/test.js:16:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:421:10)
```

I've turned off all firewalls, etc. I can't make any sense of this error. Hoping someone can help.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On `172.16.1.224` you cannot listen on `172.16.1.218` because that's not the IP of the machine you're listening on.

If you want to listen on that machine, use:

```
server.listen(6001,"172.16.1.224");
```

Comment: @Eamorr: What happens if you assign `.224` on the `.224` machine and then connect to `.224`? Is the `.218` working correctly?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply - I was on my lunch ;) But if I listen on .224 and .218, the messages still don't come through... All I'm trying to do is set up a communication link between two servers...

Comment: I tried assigning .224 on the .224 machine and then connect to .224, but it didn't work either...

Comment: @Eamorr: So if I understand correctly, `.218` works and `.224` does not work?

Comment: Hey, thanks for all your help. No, nothing works... ;( All I want to do is connect two servers together and pass messages between them ;( I can telnet into one of the servers, but I can't connect them using Node.js

Comment: @Earnorr: If I execute your second code block with my own IP and then navigate to `http://ip:6001/` I get the text `Hello World`. Does this not work for you?

Comment: That works alright, it's just I'm trying to get two servers to communicate with each other via Node.js. I'm not doing any web dev stuff.

Comment: @Earnorr: If you'd like a simple means of passing messages between servers, please have a look at https://gist.github.com/1106779.

Comment: You absolute legend! It works!!! I had my head in my hands there just before you replied. Greetings from Ireland. Thanks so much!