# Can't connect to nodejs server

Tags: node.js

I run Apache on my server. Going to my address x.x.x.x:port loads the index.html page in /var/www. When I stop the server, I can no longer connect (all good).

Now I start the node server with `node server.js` (the server.js file below is also located in /var/www).

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port, 'x.x.x.x');
console.log('Server running at http://x.x.x.x:port/');
```

This gives the error `listen EADDRNOTAVAIL`, but I am not running any other node server (there is no other process running at this port).

I have also tried omitting the IP address and just listening thus: `listen(port);`

This returns no errors, but I cannot connect to the server (Browser says: `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at x.x.x.x:p.`)

Comment: I have a feeling you are using the wrong IP, check you `ifconfig` to make sure you are using the one you think you should. Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829563/nodejs-error-eaddrnotavail-cannot-assign-requested-address You can also try listening to all interfaces with `0.0.0.0`, if you omit the hostname the default is `127.0.0.1` so you wouldn't be able to connect remotely

Comment: @Chad I have tried changing the IP to the one listed in ifconfig, but going to that address times out the connection.

Comment: To those who came here via Google: If you've hosted service on Google cloud and facing this issue, first **make sure you've added the port in the exception rules of [cloud firewall](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls) as well as in the operating systems firewall**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port is in use or not available. Try a different port like:

```
listen(88, 'x.x.x.x');
```

and see if that connects. Also, make sure that x.x.x.x is actually the ip address of your server. You can listen on all IPs by doing:

```
listen(88, '0.0.0.0');
```

or by leaving the host/ip section out entirely. If it does connect on another port, you just need to find what is using the port you want. If it's port 80, use:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

to get the program using that port.

Comment: I get the same error for any port, even ones that are free. The IP is the correct one, everything works fine with Apache.

Comment: As per your own answer, the IP *wasn't* the correct one! You were listening on one and trying to connect on another. I've updated my own answer to allow for any IP.

Comment: Accepted since you did mention it first.

Comment: I also had the error with the correct IP address, changed the IP address to 0.0.0.0 and no error. Though something else is obviously wrong as when I try to access the server from my browser all I get is a timeout.

Answer (score 3):

I have found out the problem. You don't need to specify a host name:

`listen(port, 'x.x.x.x')`

should just be

`listen(port)`

otherwise the server will not accept any connection except ones directed at the specified ip.

Comment: If no IP address is given then it will only look for connections made on the loop back address

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the port is locked up and in use..

The following command will give you a list of node processes running.

```
ps | grep node
```

To free up that port, stop the process using the following.

```
kill <processId>
```

Comment: There's no other node process running. In fact there's nothing running on that port.