# Sails.js getting "Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL" because of setting up sails-mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I've got a [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/) application that I'm using [sails-mongo](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo) on for my database. When I have the standard settings for sails-mongo in place, which appear like this the application boots right up:

```
mongodb: {
  adapter: 'sails-mongo'
}
```

However, I've created a new database and have tried setting up the connection settings in `connections.js`, but it is giving me `Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL`, which appears to be a port conflict based on [searching for this message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829563/nodejs-error-eaddrnotavail-cannot-assign-requested-address). What I have tried is below; as you can see from the comments, I've tried a number of different hosts, and have also tried switching the ports.

```
mongodb: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    // host: '192.168.1.24',
    // host: '127.0.0.1',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    //port: 27021,
    user: 'myUser',
    password: 'myPassword',
    database: 'myDb'
}
```

I've also run `netstat -lptn` in the terminal, which shows the various processes after reading ["How to Change Default Port"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367791/mongodb-how-to-change-default-port) .

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2091/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2091/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2091/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Thus, it seems there is a conflict; although `sails-mongo` wants to run, something else is blocking it. However, when attempt to change to another `port` or `host`, my `database` is no longer found.